# javascript array control with smarty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, smarty

my javascript code:

```
'{/literal}  {for $foo=1 to $app} {literal}'
// (app=5)
  var times= new Array();
  var sst='{/literal}{$st{$foo}}{literal}'; 
  var ssd='{/literal}{$dk{$foo}}{literal}'; 
  var sss='{/literal}{$sn{$foo}}{literal}'; 
 // var time+'{/literal}{$foo}{literal}'=(sayilacak_saat*3600 )+(sayilacak_dakika*60 )+         (sayilacak_saniye*1)+1;
 times.push((sst*3600 )+(ssd*60 )+(sss*1)+1);
alert(times[p]);
p=p+1;
 '{/literal}{/for}{literal}'
```

out:
         -251073(true) and another value undefined

```
     alert(times[1]);
    alert(times[2]);
    alert(times[3]);
    alert(times[4]);
    alert(times[5]);
```

all out:
           undefined

all array have value. but all undefined.

Comment: Can you please take the view source from the browser and paste here?

Comment: Where "p" is defined? (times[p] and p=p+1 lines).
I agree with @SajithNair, please post the "view source" output if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var times= new Array();

times=times+1;

You are trying to add 1 to an array, did you meant to add 1 to degeri instead?

Comment: Even after this error correction you are getting undefined?

Comment: I solved. var times= new Array() bracket to the tooth extraction.Thanks.